# Дэйтел - актуален ли ещё?

Tags: c, книги

Тяжёлая книга. По весу. ;-)
Но вот сейчас пытаюсь читать в оригинале «Modern C», «21st Century C» часто там проскакивает: проблема в том, что все учатся по книгам 80-х.

Стоит ли забросить Дэйтела и Прата на чердак?

Comment: Гораздо полезнее, на мой взгляд знакомиться с текущей документацией по C++, с чистым C по факту изменений почти нет с C99+, например ресурс  https://ru.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: Ну меня именно  С интересует. Не плюсы.

Answer (score 2):

У Дейтла куча отличных заданий и примеров. Можно просто параллельно ещё что-то по свежее читать.